# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1!\cdot2!\cdot...\cdot n!}{(2n)!} = \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

Show that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1!\cdot2!\cdot...\cdot n!}{(2n)!}=\infty$$
Intuitively, it's obvious that the sequence above diverges to $\infty$, as a product of factorials will grow much faster than $(2n)!$. However, I haven't been able to prove this rigorously, and I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: The ratio test would help.

Comment: @player3236 That's fine but maybe ratio test is  a little bit overkilling here!

Comment: @player3236 I also think that this question doesn't deserve downvotes. Even if it is elementary, the asker has shown its thoughts on that and is just asking for a right direction.

Comment: @user It is nice of you to assume that it was I who downvoted.

Comment: @player3236 Indeed I’m not assuming that.

Comment: @player3236 I was just curious about your thought on that since you also gave a hint for the solution.

Answer (score -1):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\frac{1!\cdot2!\cdot...\cdot n!}{(2n)!} =\frac{1!}{2}\cdot\frac{2!}{3\cdot 4}\cdot \ldots \cdot\frac{n!}{(2n-1)\cdot (2n)}$$

with

$$\frac{5!}{9\cdot 10}=\frac43$$

---

Or also for $n\ge 3$

- $1!\cdot2!\cdot...\cdot n! \ge 6^{n-4}(n-1)!n!$

and

- $(2n)!\le (2n)^2(2n-2)^2\ldots 2^2=(2^nn!)^2$

Comment: ... or $\frac{n!}{(2n-1)\cdot (2n)}=(n-2)!\frac{n-1}{4n-2}=(n-2)!\cdot \left(\frac14-\frac1{8n-4}\right)\le \frac16\cdot(n-2)!$ for $n\ge 2$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes I think there are many ways to show by comparison the result!

Comment: Thank you both for the help! Regarding $(2n)!=2^n\cdot n!$, isn't that true only for $(2n)!!$ ?

Comment: @William332 Yes of course! sorry I was thinking to somethign else.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not really sure what you're exactly hinting at with $\frac{5!}{9\cdot 10}$. I've been trying to do it by comparison somehow, but I haven't managed to find a smaller sequence that also diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: @William332 According to the first hint, it suffices to show that $\frac{n!}{(2n-1)\cdot (2n)}$ is increasing to conclude. I've also added a second way.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you very much!

Comment: @William332 You are welcome! Bye